# Webpack/Babel/Sass compiling into folders

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server

wondering if you could help -

Webpack is making me tear my hair out.

I have a dist folder set up with js, img and css subfolders. 
I want webpack to compile my: 
src/js/index.js into dist/js
and my src/main.scss into dist/css. I then want
webpack-dev-server to watch the dist file, so if I make a change in src it will instantly show up as I work.

It sounds simple but I've spent the best part of a day trying to make it happen.

This is what my config file looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'], //this is the correct entry point, and I have imported my main.scss into this file
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/main.js'
// it's already going to the dist folder, but is this path correct? I've tried /js/main.js - doesn't work
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:  [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '/css/styles.css',
          }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
          })
    ]

}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-sass",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For hot reloading to work

add  this in your webpack file

`const webpack = require('webpack');`

update

```
 devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
```

to

```
 devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
        hot: true,   //this is important
    },
```

then

add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` to plugins section

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '/css/styles.css',
          }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            hash: true,
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
          }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
```

Then in your `index.js`

```
if (module.hot) {
   module.hot.accept('./yourImportedComponent.js', function() {

   })
 }
```

The above steps are explained in detail on webpack website [Webpack HMR](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)